# Maximum common subgraph for DAG

Tags: python, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs, isomorphism

Given two directed acyclic graphs G1 and G2 I would like to find the biggest subgraph of G2 that is isomorph to a subgraph of G1, also known as the maximum common subgraph.

I know the general graph case in NP-Complete, but is there a solution/approximation for DAG?

Thanks

Comment: [Approximation algorithm for finding the maximum common subgraph in two DAGs from cstheory.stackexchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17689/approximation-algorithm-for-finding-the-maximum-common-subgraph-in-two-dags)

Comment: Thank you, looks like it's a no then